# axios producing strange URL

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I am working in a Vue.js & Laravel project. Here I configure axios in `main.js` file like this `axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api';`.

I am using axios in one of my component method like below.

```
methods: {
            get_words () {    
                console.log(this.word_id);  
                axios.get('/words/'+ this.word_id)
                .then(response => {
                    this.words = response.data;
                })
                .catch();    
            },
        },
```

I am getting below URL in error in console.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/words/%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%86'%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AB
```

Comment: It means that `this.word_id` is `"আল-আ'রাফ"`. (`decodeURIComponent("%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%B2-%E0%A6%86'%E0%A6%B0%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%AB")`)

Comment: Thanks @JJJ. But I am passing a number, that is word id. Thanks.

Comment: No you're not. Try `console.log(this.word_id)`.

Comment: Thanks @JJJ. Yes, I did this and got `number` value. Thanks.

Comment: Then the error is coming from some other part of the code, or this is not the real code. It's simply impossible for the value of `'/words/'+ this.word_id` to be `"/words/আল-আ'রাফ"` if `this.word_id` is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const id = this.word_id;  
axios.get(`/words/${id}`)
```

this would work for you.
Notice that it is not single quotes. It's **backticks (``)**